# Posting a link via Graph seems to now be adding a "story" and "story_tags" implicitly and overwriting my fields?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, xbox360, facebook-stream-story

Posting links via Graph to my feed, i am noticing that new "story" and "story_tags" fields are being implicitly added (without my intention). this is new behavior as of on our around 07/20/12, as if i look at links prior to that in my feed, they did not include these extra 2 fields.

one of the issues i have with this is that the "story" and/or "story_tags" field appears to be triggering something new that has unexpectedly altered the display of the link on my feed, as the new posts no longer resemble those i made 07/19 and earlier, IF the link is to a page on Facebook. specifically, my "picture," "caption" and "description" values seem to be getting overwritten by content pulled from the FB page i am linking to. if however i link to an external page then this does not occur (although curiously the "caption" field seems to now be overwritten with the link in this case, or simply ignored altogether).

furthermore, i have an Xbox 360 game that posts links to my page (it links to a page on Facebook for the game). i just did one now. when i look at it in my feed in Graph it does not contain a "story" or "story_tags" field. thus, their caption, description and picture fields are not being overwritten like mine are when i set my link to a Facebook page. how are they getting around this? is there some way i can do the same through Graph?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean exactly, but since I've started working with Graph i've noticed the story and story_tags.

As far as I could see a message is posted by a person itself, and a story is something like [user] is tagged in picture, or [user] liked a story.

And indeed the Story and story_tags do not contain a whole lot of info. But you should check for picture caption en description anyway because as I've noticed they aren't always there.

Comment: Let me ask you this: how do you get the number of likes a post has? When you click like on a FB post, the number increases by 1. I think it's a very basic info for a post.